# Attribute "actionBarSize" is already defined after adding android supportDesign dependency

Tags: android, gradle, material-design, android-support-library

Here are my gradle dependencies:
The project was working fine when i was not using `com.android.support:design:23.2.0`. I need it to implement coordinator layout in my application.

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.android.support:design:23.2.0')
    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0')
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0')
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
    compile(project(':supertoasts'))
    compile('com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2')
    compile(project(':formvalidation'))
    compile('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar')
    compile('com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1')
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0')
    compile('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.54')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4')
    compile('net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0')
    compile('com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.8.4')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It should be a comment but I do not have enough reputation to comment,
>   so I am posting this as an answer. Your actionbarsize attribute is
>   conflicting with any of the libraries/modules you are using. Read the
>   error log carefully and try to find out in which module it is
>   conflicting and remove that.

Comment: I read it but the log is not showing the module it is conflicting with

Comment: I cant post it is too long

Comment: Error:(247) Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':falconConsumer:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: if this can help find the issue